run docker vite application on local machine
now i want to run it on my local machine by using the command docker run -d tag but it is not working,
when i enter localhost:5173 the nothing appear on my browser.
my dockerfile is:
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . . 
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm install -g serve

EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["serve", "-s", "dist", "-l", "5173"]



I believe you need to run docker run with port mapping,
as such docker run -p 5173:5173
See https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports
